# Re-opening Fancybox causes my custom Ajax function to call multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using an input field and a list inside Fancybox to search and fetch clients, with 2 custom Ajax functions.

Everything works, but when re-opening the same Fancybox, my Ajax functions will get triggered multiple times.

- 1st ajax function: `searchClient()`, retrieves new list of clients
- 2nd ajax function: `selectClient()`, fetches client info and closes
  the Fancybox

Is there a way to reset the fancybox, rather than re-opening?
Or do I need to re-think my function structure? If so, how?

**UPDATE:** I just needed to reset my Fancybox content, by first assigning the content to a variable when the dom is loaded, and put the content of this variable back in the dom when Fancybox closes. This will allow the Fancybox to open the same content again, and again, without all the changes.

Credit goes to [Nick Tomlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444962/how-to-refresh-fancybox-content-when-closed/16445601?noredirect=1#16445601).

Fix:

```
// on DOM ready
var popup = $('#popup-contacts').html();

// Fancybox
$.fancybox.open({
    href: '#popup-contacts',
    padding: 0,
    autoWidth: true,
    arrows: false,
    closeBtn: false,
    scrollOutside: true,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            },
            locked: false
        }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        selectClient();
        searchClient();
    },
    afterClose: function() {
        $('#popup-contacts').html(popup);   // Reset popup content
    }
});
```

Original Code:

```
function searchClient() {
    $('.popup .search').keyup(function(k) {
        if ((k.keyCode >= 48 && k.keyCode <= 90) || (k.keyCode >= 96 && k.keyCode <= 105) || k.keyCode == 8 || k.keyCode == 46 || k.keyCode == 109 || k.keyCode == 189)
        {
            var search = $.trim($(this).val());

            var dataString = 'ajax=true&action=searchClient&search='+encodeURIComponent(search);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(this).attr('rel'),
                cache: false,
                data: dataString,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.status == 'match') {
                        $('.popup-contacts').find('ul').html(response.clients);
                        selectClient();
                    }
                    if (response.status == 'error') {
                        $('.popup-contacts').find('ul').html('<li>'+response.message+'</li>');
                    }
                },
                error: function() {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}


function selectClient() {
    $('.popup ul li').click(function() {
        var contactNumber = $(this).attr('rel');
        var dataString = 'ajax=true&action=selectClient&contactNumber='+contactNumber;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).parent().attr('rel'),
            cache: false,
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == 'success') {
                    $('textarea[name="infoTo"]').focus().val(response.clientInfo);
                    $.fancybox.close();
                }
                if (response.status == 'error') {

                }
            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
    });
}


// Open Fancybox

$('textarea[name="infoTo"]').focus(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '')
    {
        $.fancybox.open({
            href: '#popup-contacts',
            padding: 0,
            autoWidth: true,
            arrows: false,
            closeBtn: false,
            scrollOutside: true,
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    css: {
                        'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                    },
                    locked: false
                }
            },
            afterShow: function() {
                selectClient();
                searchClient();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using FB version 1 or 2?

Comment: @megaSteve4 Version 2. But I fixed it myself. See my **UPDATE**.

Comment: @jlmmns please add an answer if this has been solved (you can accept it after 2 days) - it will stop the question appearing in the unanswered list

Comment: @Pete Thanks for bringing that to my attention! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I just needed to reset my Fancybox content, by first assigning the content to a variable when the dom is loaded, and put the content of this variable back in the dom when Fancybox closes. This will allow the Fancybox to open the same content again, and again, without all the changes.

Credit goes to [Nick Tomlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444962/how-to-refresh-fancybox-content-when-closed/16445601?noredirect=1#16445601).

Fix:

```
// on DOM ready
var popup = $('#popup-contacts').html();

// Fancybox
$.fancybox.open({
    href: '#popup-contacts',
    padding: 0,
    autoWidth: true,
    arrows: false,
    closeBtn: false,
    scrollOutside: true,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            },
            locked: false
        }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        selectClient();
        searchClient();
    },
    afterClose: function() {
        $('#popup-contacts').html(popup);   // Reset popup content
    }
});
```