# How to refresh Fancybox content when closed?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Is there a way to reset the fancybox instance or refresh the contents of it, when closed?
Note that it grabs content from a div on the same page.

I want it to display the content like it was first loaded into the dom, when re-opening the fancybox.

I guess this is more of a javascript/jQuery thing, than a Fancybox thing, right?

```
$.fancybox.open({
    href: '#popup',
    padding: 0,
    autoWidth: true,
    arrows: false,
    closeBtn: false,
    scrollOutside: true,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            },
            locked: false
        }
    },
    afterClose: function() {
        // Reset or refresh here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the sort of changes you are making to the target `div`, but you will not be able to "reset" them without reloading the page, or performing a funky Ajax call to the page and getting the div contents from there.

The simplest way of getting around this would be to store the markup of that div in a variable (using jQuery's `html()`, and "reset" that div using the variable in your `afterClose()` callback.

**JS**

```
var content = $('#popup').html(); // store content on documentReady()

$.fancybox.open({
    href: '#popup',
    padding: 0,
    autoWidth: true,
    arrows: false,
    closeBtn: false,
    scrollOutside: true,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            },
            locked: false
        }
    },
    afterClose: function(){
        $('#popup').html(content);
    }
});
```

It might be best to use fancybox's `beforeLoad` callback, in conjunction with this, to do this for all of your content, but as you seem to be loading a single `div`, this should work.

Comment: there is not an `onLoad` callback in fancybox v2.x

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Nick! Nice and simple solution.

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help. Thanks for mentioning that @jfk i've updated it to use a v2 callback that should be approximate.